# how to rewrite this SQL Query without the or 's

Tags: sql

so the 672  is the amount of quarters in a week and i need the avg(value) of all quarters of 5 weeks on the same day on the same quarter

```
select value,  DATEADD(MINUTE, a.QuarterNumber * 15, '2000-01-01') AS [Timestamp]
from measurements.Archive a
INNER JOIN measurements.Points p ON a.PointId = p.Id
INNER JOIN fifthcore..cm_lod_devices ld ON ld.Uuid = p.LogicalDeviceUuid
WHERE ld.Id IN (SELECT Value FROM @LodDeviceIds)
AND (
a.QuarterNumber = 510176 
OR a.QuarterNumber = 510176 - 672 
OR a.QuarterNumber = 510176 - (672*2)
OR a.QuarterNumber = 510176 - (672*3)
OR a.QuarterNumber = 510176 - (672*4)
OR a.QuarterNumber = 510176 - (672*5)
...
)
```

Comment: something like `(a.QuarterNumber - 510176) % 672 = 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know which is the last number you want. But the principal would be to find how many ones you want. In your example i will assume 5 as the max multiplier.

So knowing the firt quarter which is `510176` ani would find the min quarter which would be in your example `510176 - (672*5)` and i would test the integer part of the division with 672:

```
select value,  DATEADD(MINUTE, a.QuarterNumber * 15, '2000-01-01') AS [Timestamp]
from measurements.Archive a
INNER JOIN measurements.Points p ON a.PointId = p.Id
INNER JOIN fifthcore..cm_lod_devices ld ON ld.Uuid = p.LogicalDeviceUuid
WHERE ld.Id IN (SELECT Value FROM @LodDeviceIds)
AND ((510176 - (672*5))- a.QuarterNumber)%672 = 0
AND a.QuarterNumber>510176 - (672*5)
AND a.QuarterNumber<=510176
```

On the above you would only need to change `5` to the number of your expected quarters -1.

Answer (score 1):

Use `in` instead:

```
where a.QuarterNumber in (510176, 510176 - 672, 510176 - (672*2), 510176 - (672*3), 510176 - (672*4)
                          510176 - (672*5), . . .)
```

If there is some sort of coding scheme, and you essentially want in infinite list, then use modulo arithmetic.  In many databases, this will work:

```
where mod(a.QuarterNumber, 672) = mod(510176, 672) and a.QuarterNumber <= 510176
```

Comment: mod is the oracle way of doing modulo. for sqlite, postgre, mysql, you'll use `%`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Gordon proposes you can also express this with a join. I'm using a CTE here:

```
with t(n) as ( values 0 union all select n+1 from t where n<? ) 
select value,  DATEADD(MINUTE, a.QuarterNumber * 15, '2000-01-01') AS [Timestamp]
from measurements.Archive a
INNER JOIN measurements.Points p ON a.PointId = p.Id
INNER JOIN fifthcore..cm_lod_devices ld ON ld.Uuid = p.LogicalDeviceUuid

JOIN t ON a.QuarterNumber = 510176 - (672*t.n)

WHERE ld.Id IN (SELECT Value FROM @LodDeviceIds)
```